# Invalid YAML: Aliases are not suported

Tags: networking, netplan

I'm getting this error with network manager

```
12:1: Invalid YAML: Aliases are not supported
```

This is the YAML file:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Your indentation is probably causing your problem. Edit the .yaml and use two spaces for indents. Also, this .yaml does not use NetworkManager... if that was your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces matter.

Add a space after every colon:

`addresses:[10.0.2.15]`
becomes
`addresses: [10.0.2.15]`

`nameservers`  needs a colon:
`nameservers:`

And make sure your indentation is right.

example: The gateway4 and nameservers line should line up with the addresses line above it, but you have an extra space.

```
...
addresses: ...
 gateway4: ...
```

finally the addresses under nameservers needs another space like this:

```
nameservers:
  addresses: [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error as you and the issue was having an empty newline at the end of the file (if you see the error it's at line 12 that's empty). In your case there are other issues as @jeffk mentioned but the first one that throws the error is the blank line.

I just removed the extra newline and the config worked